# Redirect back withInput() output the data in control

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to redirect back with input, but the data isn't being put back into the input controls. Am I missing an output directive in the value of the input? If so, what is the code to do that in my view?

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'owner_firstname'       => 'required|min:2|max:30',
    'owner_lastname'        => 'required|min:2|max:30',
    'partner_firstname'     => 'required|min:2|max:30',
    'partner_lastname'      => 'min:2|max:30',
    'baby_firstname'        => 'min:2|max:30',
    'baby_lastname'         => 'min:2|max:30',
    'month'                 => 'not_in:0',
    'day'                   => 'not_in:0',
    'year'                  => 'numeric|digits:4',
    'guests_message'        => 'required|min:30|max:5000'
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect()->back()
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->withInput();
}

<input type="text" id="owner_firstname" value="{{ what do I put here }}">
```

Comment: Did you use the `old` helper in your view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `old` helper to restore the previous values and add a `name` attribute to your input.

```
<input type="text" id="owner_firstname" name="owner_firstname" value="{{ old('first_name') }}">
```

For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-old